# When to use pointers vs direct members for a struct

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, struct

So I found [this](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/) amazing tutorial on sockets in C. So far, it all makes sense, but I was curious that I saw structs made with both pointer and without pointers. I was confused about when you should or shouldn't use pointers for structs.

I found this example in the tutorial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 2000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message, server_reply[MAX_LENGTH];

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        puts("Could not create socket :(");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("173.194.121.2");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        puts("Connection error.");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected!\n");

    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

So I decided to convert the server variable to a pointer and see what happened. Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 2000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in *server;
    char *message, server_reply[MAX_LENGTH];

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        puts("Could not create socket :(");
    }

    server->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("173.194.121.2");
    server->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server->sin_port = htons(80);

    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)server, sizeof(*server)) < 0) {
        puts("Connection error.");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected!\n");

    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

This also compiled fine, but gave my a `Segmentation fault: 11` when I ran it.

So my question is why didn't this code work, and how can I know when I will need a pointer to a struct, or a normal struct. Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason to use pointers in this case. In fact, using pointers will lead to quite a few of those crashes until you learn how to deal with them. The thing is, don't use pointers unless you have to, and in this case you really don't have to.

Comment: Have you *ever* studied pointers? Your using pointers is completely wrong..

Comment: @ikh Not in a long time. I haven't done C in a while so I am kinda relearning the little that I knew. What is wrong with the way I'm using them?

Comment: @addison below answers explain correct usage >o< In addition, please remember that: Initialize variables (including pointers) before you use it - you haven't initialize `struct sockaddr_in *server`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first version, you have a full struct declared which means that the memory for the struct is put on the stack.

In the second version, you declare a pointer to the struct, but allocate no memory for it, so when you try to address the non-existent members of the struct, you segfault.

If you change the second one to allocate memory for the structure:

```
struct sockaddr_in *server = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

and then remember to `free(server);` before exiting, you will be handling the memory correctly.

To answer the second part of your question, you would likely only need a pointer to a structure if you need to store the data (in this case, the connection info) in some other data structure to keep track of it, or if you need to pass it to another routine for some reason.

However, for the latter case, using the `&` operator to get the address a structure on the stack to use as a pointer to pass to a routine is commonly done, as in the `connect()` call in the first routine where it does just this with this argument: `(struct sockaddr *)&server`

Answer (score 0):

server is a pointer. What does it point to? You didn't tell. server *could* point to a struct sock_addr_in, but it doesn't.

It's like a car driving just fine on a road, but you are attempting to drive it on a road sign.

Answer (score 0):

If the API you are passing a pointer to intends to dereference that pointer a store a value inside it on your behalf, you need to pass it a valid memory location so that the storage action will succeed.

If the API you are passing a pointer to intends only to pass the same back to you (like via a callback function), then the pointer value can be any value that makes sense to you when you get the value back.